# Magento 2.3.3 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getReviewsCount()

Tags: magento2, review

I have upgrade Magento version from 2.3.1 to 2.3.3 and now I am getting an error on the product

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getReviewsCount()
```

My code for getting review count

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$reviewCount = $_product->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount();
```

in one custom module, I have got product review and now it's said that getReviewsCount() function is not found anyone has an idea how to get product review count in 2.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this file `/vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/ReviewRenderer.php` Line no. 131

**Try This :-**

```
 $_product->getReviewsCount();
```